# Schema validation warning from forwarding SMS with Twilio/Flask

Tags: python, sms, twilio

My code takes an incoming SMS text message, extracts the body, and forwards the body to another number. (tPhone is the Twilio number and ePhone is the number I want messages forwarded to)

```
import twilio.twiml
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from passwords import *

client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def AlertService():
    TheMessage=request.form.get("Body")
    if (TheMessage != None):
        print(TheMessage)
        client.messages.create(to=ePhone, from_=tPhone, body=TheMessage)
    return str(TheMessage)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0")
```

The code works (message gets forwarded) but the Twilio debugger tells me

> Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> Warning - 12200
>
> Schema validation warning
>
> The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema.

How can I fix the XML being sent to Twilio?

---

Edit: Some things I've found. Even if I set 'TheMessage' to a predefined string (ex. `TheMessage="hello"`) I receive the same error from Twilio.

Additionally, if I try to generate and send the XML, I still get the same error.

```
    resp = twiml.Response()
    XML = resp.message(TheMessage)
    print(XML)
    client.messages.create(body=str(XML),to=ePhone,from_=tPhone)
```

The code fails to send if I try `body=XML` and if I try `body=str(XML)` it just sends the XML as plaintext.

Comment: Make sure your phone numbers are being passed as Strings and not as ints.

Comment: @JakeConway They're being stored as strings in my passwords.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

At the moment it looks as though you are using the [REST API to forward the SMS message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages). While you can do it this way, it's easier to use [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to do it within the request using the [`<Message>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message). In your second example you appear to be trying to use TwiML and the REST API together and that's not going to work.

So, you just want to build up a TwiML response, add the message to it if there is an incoming message and then use the [`<Message>` attributes `to` and `from`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message#attributes) to forward it on to your phone number. Like this:

```
import twilio.twiml
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from passwords import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def AlertService():
    TheMessage=request.form.get("Body")
    resp = twiml.Response()
    if (TheMessage != None):
        resp.message(TheMessage, to=ePhone)
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0")
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I had to remove "from_=tPhone" (Attribute 'from_' is not allowed to appear in element 'Message'.), but after that everything worked, thank you.

Comment: Bah, sorry about that. Didn't have time to test. Will edit my answer. Cheers!